# Book about a female protagonist who's transported from the real world to a fantasy world, then back again

Tags: story-identification, books

I can't remember a ton of details but this is driving me crazy. Found this book in a used book store in the early 2000s. I think it was written in the 70s-80s, but could be wrong.

The protagonist is a female who would suddenly just go from our world to a fantasy world. She'd be in the fantasy world for a long time, then at some point she'd just end up back in regular reality. I remember one passage in particular where she is in the present not fantasy world. She is riding on the back of a motorcycle with her boyfriend driving. She describes how he goes through a series of almost red lights. Like how you speed up on yellow to miss the red light then hit a succession of lights like that. Then another scene in the present where she is listening to a record player with her friends.

In the fantasy world I remember some dude, maybe he wore feathers and leathers? Something about his description seemed vaguely native American. She was into him, they start kissing I think?? And she gets transported back. Also in the fantasy world they are developing more powerful weapons of war (still nothing like what we have, talking about medieval style weapons on a wooden ship) and someone is musing/concerned about it.

Not a lot to go on I know but it is driving me crazy. Also vaguely recall that her boyfriend in regular reality reminds her of, or actually is, a character in the fantasy world, like a bad guy. She muses about how people can be different in different times/circumstances. Also something about a troupe of performers in the fantasy world. It is not *Alosha*, by the way. Oh and it is part of a trilogy. I don't think it was the first book. I remember trying to find the others on Amazon but they were not available. This was back when I still had my copy.

Adding this - I read the second book and the main character did not know how or why she would end up in the other world. It would just happen randomly.

I think the book might have been published by TOR. The cover was classic high fantasy style art.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Maybe [The Time of the Dark](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/176277.The_Time_of_the_Dark) by Barbara Hambly? The descriptions I can find online don't give me enough information about the parts set in our world to be sure, though.

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern First thing I thought of, given the start of the question, but the description of Gil's love life doesn't match (in either world).

Comment: @Astrid_Redfern: My own immediate thought was of another Hambly trilogy, *The Silent Tower, The Silicon Mage, Dog Wizard*, but the other details don't fit with my memories of these books.

Comment: There's some similarity to [Moonheart](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/618174.Moonheart) by Charles de Lint, but I don't recall any weapons being developed, or any troupe of performers. The person in "feathers and leathers" sounds familiar though, and there was a biker in it.

Comment: Maybe it IS Time of the Dark, either way, I'm reading that book now lol. So by the time I get to the second book I'll update here.